# Cost of calling DispatchQueue.main.async in iOS GCD

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I found some code example recently

```
func stpDispatchToMainThreadIfNecessary(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        block()
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: block)
    }
}
```

It looks like if we will wrap all blocks inside DispatchQueue.main.async no matter which thread it is it will technically work.
The question is why check for the main thread?
Does it add some optimization? If yes - where to read about it and how to benchmark it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important bit if the `async` dispatch.

If `stpDispatchToMainThreadIfNecessary` is called from the main thread, `block` is executed synchronously, while if the func is called from a background thread, due to the `async(execute:)` call, `block` is executed asynchronously.

This means that when called from the main thread, due to the sync execution, `block` will be executed sooner than if it was also wrapped in a Dispatch async call.

You could change the `async(execute:)` to `sync(execute:)`, which in case of the main thread would result in no delay compared to simply calling `block()`, however, you should not be dispatching synchronously to the main thread from a background thread, because that might freeze the UI.

So checking whether the func was called from the main thread and in this case synchronously executing `block`, while asynchronously dispatching it to the main thread from any other thread ensures that there is no unnecessary blocking of the main thread when calling the func from another thread, but also no unnecessary delay when calling the func from the main thread.